# w2ui toolbar - is there a way to fill menu items dynamically

Tags: javascript, toolbar, w2ui

I want to fill my w2ui toolbar menu item dynamically using javascript. I tried using: `document.getElementById` but it didn't work since theres no id for the dropdown menu.

the section processes is the one that I'm trying to fill dynamically

```
ToolBarView.prototype.buildView = function(processController) {

    $('#MDItoolbar').w2toolbar({
        name: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            { type: 'button',  id: 'saveProcess' ,  name: 'saveProcess', caption: 'save Process', icon: 'fa-check', checked: true },
            { type: 'break',  id: 'break0' },
            { type: 'button',  id: 'NewProcess' ,  name: 'NewProcess', caption: 'New Process', icon: 'fa-check', checked: true },
            { type: 'break', id: 'break1' , name: 'break1' },
            { type: 'menu',   id: 'processes', caption: 'Drop Down', img: 'icon-folder', 
                name:'processes',
                items: [
                    { text: 'Item 1', img: 'icon-page' }, 
                    { text: 'Item 2', img: 'icon-page' }, 
                    { text: 'Item 3', img: 'icon-page' }
                ]
            },
            { type: 'break', id: 'break3' ,name:'break3'},
            { type: 'spacer',name:'spacer' }
        ]
    });

    w2ui.toolbar.on('*', function (event) { 
        console.log('EVENT: '+ event.type + ' TARGET: '+ event.target, event);
        if (event.target =='saveProcess')
        {
            var saveProcess = new SaveProcessView("save the process",processController);
        }

        if (event.target =='NewProcess')
        {
            processController.NewProcess();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to `get()` the toolbar menu ( see http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2toolbar.get ), then you need to replace / extend the `items` array of the toolbar menu:

```
w2ui.toolbar.get('processes').items = [
    { text: 'New Item 1', img: 'icon-page' },
    { text: 'New Item 2', img: 'icon-page' }
];
```

I strongly recommend you give your items an `id`, too ( see http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2toolbar.items ).